# Installed a new motherboard on my Toshiba Satellite P855-34P

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, boot

Got the recovery discs from Toshiba. 1st it wouldnt start until i disabled the PXE option, did this but now it wont boot because it asks for a proper boot partition. It is set to boot from HDD
I checked the hard drive on my other laptop and the windows partition seems to be there.
So theoretically it should boot.
Run out of ideas.Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks
JM

Comment: The motherboard is already changed, so not sure what your telling me.So what is the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the OS again, do not have any thing else plugged in that may change a drive letter.

Comment: I have tried to install the operating system 4 times already.from the supplied discs. Right at the end it says press the fininsh button to restart the computer, then it says instert boot media and press any key etc. Windows is installed because ive checked on another laptop. It spins up OK and i checked it with chkdsk etc. Its a real puzzler this one.

Comment: Yes indeed, I have had that happen only one time to me, and it changed a drive letter with a usb device plugged in, it was a long time ago. Check over all you boot drive options make sure they point to HHD-0 not IDE, but SATA if available. There must be something simple doing this....

Comment: OK, well it is allocated as a sata and uef, when i do chckdsk in command prompt it is allocated as /f, should it be /c. if so how did you change it.  Thanks Jack

Comment: IM beginning to wonder if the Toshiba recovery discs only work if they find a hidden recovery partition, but im assured by their tech they will work on a reformated HDD. The windows key is embedded in the disc. So even if i wanted to redownload windows from MS i wouldnt have a key to do it. This system sucks.  JM

Comment: I never used chkdsk to test HDDs, sorry, so I would not know about the switches.... I always use the testing program that the manufacturers have from their website. All are free, it can be burned to a CD and is bootable. With the Recovery, usually the CD/DVD will look for a recovery partition, it if finds one it will allow the recovery run from the partition. If it does not find one it will run from the CD/DVD. Your key will work if you have the same version recovery disk as labeled on your laptop. I have used NON-branded install disks with the COA and had a good install.

Comment: I use Hiren's Boot CD to do all my testing. It has a great collection of freeware and shareware products that will test any part of your pc you need. It already has all the hhd manufactures testing suites on it, a version of "mini XP" to inspect your drive contents other stress tests, much more.

Comment: OK Jack i'll give this a try see what it comes up with. Thanks again